# Serializar lista de objetos para JSON: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, webforms

Estou tentando *Serializar* uma lista de objetos para *Json* e tenho recebi o seguinte erro:

An exception of type

> 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Web.Extensions.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: A circular reference was detected while
>   serializing an object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Pais_FE2360F9C3DD9892003FC5DC33EF9BD07698CFF62033EE442867F74C88F09AC7'.

*Tenho usado:*

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void GetListaPais(string prefixText, string contextKey)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(AuxiliarControler.ListaPais(prefixText,contextKey));
    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Context.Response.Flush();
    Context.Response.Write(json);
}
```

*Método que obtêm a lista de `Pais`:*

```
public static List<Pais> ListaPais(string nomePais, int IDIdioma)
{
    using (entidadesIUS entidades = new entidadesIUS())
    {
        return entidades.Pais.Where(p => p.IDIdioma == IDIdioma && 
            p.Pais1.Contains(nomePais)).ToList();
    }
}
```

*Entidade `Pais`*

```
public partial class Pais
{
    public Pais()
    {
        this.CAL = new HashSet<CAL>();
        this.Clientes = new HashSet<Clientes>();
    }

    public int IDPais { get; set; }
    public string Pais1 { get; set; }
    public int IDIdioma { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<CAL> CAL {get; set; }
    public virtual Idiomas Idiomas {get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Clientes> Clientes {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "Dá pau" é o comentário mais subjetivo possível. Qual o erro? O que você já tentou fazer para sana-lo?

Comment: Qual é a IDE que você está usando?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Isto acontece porque possivelmente você tem uma entidade A que referencia uma entidade B e que em algum lugar volta a referenciar A.

Para resolver, anote o seguinte nas entidades dependentes:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual Idioma Idioma { get; set; }
```

Ou, numa abordagem global, dá um pouco mais de trabalho. [Esta abordagem vale para o pacote JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).

## 1. Implemente um [`JsonResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) que use a configuração desejada

O meu ficou assim:

```
public class CustomJsonResult : JsonResult
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
        ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    };

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (this.JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet &&
            string.Equals(context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("GET request not allowed");
        }

        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.ContentType = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ContentType) ? this.ContentType : "application/json";

        if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;
        }

        if (this.Data == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Data, Settings));
    }
}
```

## 2. Derive a classe básica [`Controller`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) e implemente um `override` para o método [`Json`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee430908(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
public abstract class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, System.Text.Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
    {
        return new CustomJsonResult
        {
            Data = data,
            ContentType = contentType,
            ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
            JsonRequestBehavior = behavior
        };
    }
}
```

## 3. Teste

Fiz um teste para pegar 10 cidades no meu sistema que ficou assim:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> SelecionarDez()
{
    var cidades = await db.Cidades.Take(10).ToListAsync();
    return Json(cidades, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Bela ampliação da resposta, muito bom.

Comment: Verdade @Marconi ! Implementei em um projeto e rodou perfeitamente!

Comment: @MaurícioJúnior Essa resposta do Cigano é sensacional. Bom que ela pode te ajudar :)

Comment: Estou com dificuldades para implementar esta solução, imagino que no `Controller` devo substituir: `public class ColaboradorController : Controller`  por `public class ColaboradorController : CustomJsonResult` , é isso ?

Comment: Não. `CustomJsonResult` é uma classe. `Controller` derivado de `System.Web.Controller` é outra.

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu implemento o uso dessa classe em meu `Controller`? O `Controller` contém alguns `ActionResult` e `JsonResult`, exemplo:  `public JsonResult MontarGridColaborador()` que retornar dados do BD (retorno com referência circular) e quero implementar essa solução para exibir os dados na `View`.

Comment: Não, a classe é em separado do `Controller`. O `Controller` que implementa `public JsonResult MontarGridColaborador()` herdará de `Controller` e o problema de referência circular acaba porque este `Controller` ancestral reimplementa `JsonResult`.

Comment: Ok!, Depois que eu salvei as  `classes` dentro da pasta `Controller` e funcionou, perfeito!

Comment: No meu caso fica dando a seguinte Mensagem: 'Controller' is an ambiguos reference between 'ERP4.Helpers.Controller' and 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller' como faço para Declarar essa controller nova sem dar conflito com a padrão do Mvc?

Comment: @EdenilsonBila `public abstract class Controller: System.Web.Mvc.Controller { ... }`

Answer (score 9):

Recomendo a utilização [desta biblioteca](http://james.newtonking.com/json). Ela é altamente difundida na comunidade .net.
No meu caso eu utilizo o recurso abaixo para evitar referências cíclicas e ignorar valores nulos no json no momento da serialização.

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter
    .SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter
    .SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```

Está configuração é feita no arquivo Global.asax de uma aplicação WebApi. Você teria que ver no seu caso onde colocá-la.

Comment: Ele já está usando a JSON.NET. Possivelmente na época que tive que resolver isso essa configuração nem existia. +1.