# Erro no retorno de JsonResult

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-datatables

Estou com dificuldades para entender esse problema:

Quando clico na linha do `Datatable` para editar os dados do Cliente ocorre erro sempre que o Cliente tem um Contato ou um Endereço cadastrado e isso é muito comum.

Este é código acionado quando faço um duplo click na linha do `Datatable`:

**VIEW**

```
        // BUSCA DETALHES DO CLIENTE
        $.ajax({
            url: "ObterClientePorId",
            type: "post",
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json charset=uft-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "id": id }),
            success: function (data) {

                if (data != null) {
                    alert("Nome: " + data.Result.NMCLIENTE);
                    var url = "Create?id=" + id;
                    window.location.href = url;
                }

            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                alert(err.message);
            }
        });
```

**Controller:**

```
 public JsonResult ObterClientePorId(int id)
    {
        var ocliente = _IRepositorio.ListarClientePorId(id);
        return Json(new { Result = ocliente }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Repositório:**

```
public TBCliente ListarClientePorId(int? id)
    {
        return _repositorio.Clientes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.TBCLIENTEID == id);

    }
```

**PRINT DA EXECUÇÃO:**

**View:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Controller**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Repositório:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Controller**

Observe que o Cliente tem um Endereço cadastrado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**View:**

Aqui ocorre o erro, sempre quando o Cliente tem um Endereço ou um Contato que é comum:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!

**Erro quando dou clique duplo **

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O seu ajax está retornando um erro. Se estivesse retornando success iria mostrar a sua string "Nome: algo". Como ele está caindo no erro, ele está mostrando undefined. Troque o seu ajax error pela seguinte função -> error: function (result) { alert(result.responseText); }, e veja qual erro está vindo do seu servidor.

Comment: Nikofoxxx alterei o alert como você sugeriu e o erro retornado é referência circular: '{System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapperWithoutRelationships<System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.TBCliente_B9C53E0400B8BDC8BC0A93F5D237FB906B8CC8C546FFFAC9D110EE207EDC782C>}', eu vou adicionar o print do alert no corpo da pergunta para ficar melhor o entendimento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está com um problema de referência circular. O serializador JSON tenta serializar uma entidade A, que faz referência a uma entidade B, e que por algum caminho faz novamente referência a A.

[Já existe uma resposta pra isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35109/serializar-lista-de-objetos-para-json-a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-s/35153#35153).

Adicionalmente, melhor não usar a abordagem por repositório quando usa Entity Framework. Não traz vantagem alguma e ainda te traz problemas.