# Erro ao listar Dados via Json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

Estou usando um *method* para retornar um objeto do tipo **JSON** porém não está listando as informações:

Meu *Controller*

```
   public ActionResult GetDados()
    {
        int codigoVenda = 2;

        try
        {
            SistemaDBEntities db = new SistemaDBEntities();

                List<ItensVenda> itensVenda = new List<ItensVenda>();
                itensVenda = db.ItensVenda.Where(s => s.CodigoVenda == codigoVenda).ToList();

                //var venda = db.Venda.Where(s => s.Codigo == codigoVenda).ToList();

                return Json(itensVenda, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Meu *Script*

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({           
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Venda/GetDados",
        success: function (itensVenda) {

            if (dados != null) {

                $('#tbody').children().remove();

                $(itensVenda).each(function (i) {

                    var tbody = $('#tbody');
                    var tr = "<tr>";
                    tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].CodigoProduto;
                    tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].Quantidade;
                    tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].PrecoUnitario;

                    tr += "<td>" + "<button class='btn btn-info' onclick=Editar(" + itensVenda[i].Id + ")>" + "Editar";
                    tr += "<td>" + "<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick=Deletar(" + itensVenda[i].Id + ")>" + "Deletar";

                    tbody.append(tr);



                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Tenho quase certeza que ele não lista por causa desse erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o que está errado?

Comment: Creio que essa não é a melhor abordagem para o que busca, eu usaria partialView para preencher a tabela. Mas, tente acessar a url **localhost:63729/venda/GetDados** e poste o erro que está aparecendo

Comment: Aparece esse erro:
**Foi detectada uma referência circular ao serializar um objeto do tipo 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Venda_9F946F25ADE24F28CDCA309E65A9E7ECE50AF4C1B01232ED376A7B4DCF436E82'.**

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nesta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35153/20615), que você conseguirá resolver seu problema. E edite sua pergunta e adicione o erro nela, fica mais fácil entender seu real problema.

Comment: Na verdade tem um pouco de diferença uma é WebForms a outra é ASPNet MVC e além do mais setando o `db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` (configuração do EntityFramework, que é recomendado tirar) evita de dar o erro e soluciona o problema sem tem que fazer um outra classe e configuração. Claro a resposta proposta também é uma solução, mas, em outro momento em outro caso, acredito que seria legal ter as soluções para ambos! Não acho DUPLICATA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O [*ProxyCreationEnabled*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.proxycreationenabled(v=vs.113).aspx) está habilitado, coloque uma linha assim que vai funcionar:

```
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Exemplo total:

```
public ActionResult GetDados()
{
    int codigoVenda = 2;

    try
    {
        SistemaDBEntities db = new SistemaDBEntities();     

        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        List<ItensVenda> itensVenda = db.ItensVenda.Where(s => s.CodigoVenda == codigoVenda).ToList();      

        return Json(itensVenda, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Inclusive eu colocaria mais essa:

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Para não carregar os dados do relacionamento (Boa prática) e se precisa de algum relacionamento use Include.

***Observação:*** realmente a dica proposta pelo OP nos comentários é a melhor trabalhe com `PartialView`.

Comment: Parabéns @Cezar, obrigado, agora funcionou...
Muito Obrigado!

Comment: depois que utiliza o configuration é necessário volta-lo ao normal para as outras controllers? ou essa config fica apenas na action inserida?