# Recursividade no entity-framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou iniciando no c# e estou tendo umas dificuldades com o Entity-Framework. Tenho o seguinte cenário:

```
public InstituicaoMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    HasKey(t => t.IdInstituicao);

    // Properties
    Property(t => t.Nome)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(255);
}

public CampanhaMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.IdCampanha);

    // Properties
    this.Property(t => t.Texto)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(160);

    this.Property(t => t.DataEdicao)
        .IsFixedLength()
        .HasMaxLength(8)
        .IsRowVersion();

    // Relationships
    this.HasRequired(t => t.Instituicao)
        .WithMany(t => t.Campanhas)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdInstituicao);
}
```

Estou implementando um CRUD de campanhas, e no momento estou cirando o método "`IEnumerable<Campanha> List()`" (que lista todas as campanhas cadastradas).

Aparentemente esta funcionando. Para cada campanha retornada na "lista" há um objeto Instituicao dentro. Até ae tudo bem. O problema é que dentro da Instituicao há uma lista de campanhas, que há instituições, que há outra lista de campanhas... e assim vai.

1 - Estou preocupado com o consumo de memória e/ou algum problema que essa recursividade pode ocasionar.

2 - Estou enviando este retorno para a View via JSON (pois a paginação da grid será feita com AJAX/JSON).

```
return new ContentResult
{
    Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
    ContentType = "application/json"
};
```

Neste retorno, estou recebendo um erro de "looping infinito" do JsonConvert. De fato, pois o objeto campanhas está recursivo.

O que posso fazer?

Comment: Sua dúvida se parece muito com uma pergunta que fiz aqui:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35109/serializar-lista-de-objetos-para-json-a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a anotação  em sua lista, ou mapear para ignorar, em sua configuração. O primeiro modo é mais simples, bastando fazer isso:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual Instituicao Instituicao{get;set;}
```

Da segunda forma, ficaria assim seu `CampanhaMap`:

```
public CampanhaMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.IdCampanha);

    // Properties
    this.Property(t => t.Texto)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(160);

    this.Property(t => t.DataEdicao)
        .IsFixedLength()
        .HasMaxLength(8)
        .IsRowVersion();

    // Relationships
    this.HasRequired(t => t.Instituicao)
        .WithMany(t => t.Campanhas)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdInstituicao);

    this.Ignore(t => t.Instituicao);

}
```

Ou, se não que isso, pode desabilitar o `Leazy Loading` do EF em seu contexto. Algo parecido com isso:

```
  public YouContext(): base("name=SchoolDBEntities")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: ainda existe uma terceira opção, informar ao JSON.NET que o tipo Instituicao e Campanha são referencias, isto pode ser feito ao colocar o atributo `[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]` ou `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` nas classes, ou utilizando a opção `PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`, mas no caso dele, por se tratar de um relacionamento `n:n`, isto pode vir a gerar um objeto JSON enorme.

Answer (score -1):

Uma outra maneira seria vc criar uma classe própria para suas necessidades.

Utilizando o AutoMapper no seu projeto e não utilizar as classes do EF para exibição e retorno.

Tem uma matéria do Eduardo Pires falando sobre SOLID .

Eu aconselho a não utilizar o Lazy Loading pois ele faz consultas separadas na base. A Vandagem é que quando você precisa do dado é só chamar a propriedade que a consulta é feita automaticamente.

Conselho utilizar o Eager Loading onde vc diz para o EF o que vc precisa carregar.

Eu me matei muito com EF6 não é fácil é bem confuso e não tem muitas materias sobre. Aconselho ver esses sites...

http://www.eduardopires.net.br/?s=solid&submit=Pesquisar

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/